# How to reference a type in a module that has a type with the same name as the module it is in?

Tags: swift

I am trying to reference a type inside a framework that has a type whose name is the same as the framework. Easier to explain in code:

In Framework `Something`

```
public struct A { ... }
public class Something { ... }
```

In Framework `OtherFramework`

```
public struct A { ... }
```

Then on the main project I import both modules:

```
import Something
import OtherFramework

let myA = A() // 'A' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
```

And if I do

```
import Something
import OtherFramework

let myA = Something.A() // 'A' is not a member type of 'Something'
```

Is there any way to reference `A` in `Something` other than changing the framework?

Comment: That's a fantastic questions! I haven't found a way so far, I assumed it's a bug.

Comment: It's a work around, but you could probably split your class into extensions that only deal with one of the frameworks.

Comment: @Aleph7 I just went ahead and created an issue for this: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1389 I hope you're okay with that

Comment: @HAS I did too, but there was already a ticket for it: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-898

Comment: @Aleph7 I searched and couldn't find anything! But Jordan already marked mine as a dupe of that one, too.

Answer (score 10):

One possible way is not to import the whole module, import only the specific types you need, e.g. to import a class `Something` in module `Something`:

```
import class Something.Something
```

Answer (score 5):

One solution I found is to create a separate .swift file with this:

```
import Something
typealias SomethingA = A
```

And then

```
import Something
import OtherFramework

let myA = SomethingA()
```

Comment: So simple yet so genius. Thank you for this!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
import Something
import OtherFramework

let myA = Something.Something.A()
```